# How to pass props to a styled component in emotion? Using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js

I am using styled by emotion at:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
```

I am trying to pass props to a styled component like the guide mentions:

https://emotion.sh/docs/styled

It doesn't work for some reason.  I use TypeScript as well. I pass props to my styled component called StyleWrapper here:

```
const ex: React.FunctionComponent<exProps> = props => {
  return (
    <StyleWrapper someNumber = {props.someNumber}
...
    </StyleWrapper >
  )
}
```

and in StyleWrapper:

```
const ToolsHeaderColumn = styled.div`
  padding-top: ${props => props.someNumber };
`
```

What I get is an error in compilation:

```
"Property 'someNumber ' does not exist on type 
'Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, 
HTMLDivElement>, "children" | "style" | "title" | 
"color" | "hidden" | "defaultChecked" | "defaultValue" |     "suppressContentEditableWarning" | ... 243 more ... 
| "css"> & { ...; }'.ts(2339)
"
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

by [this docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript), you can make it like:

```
type ToolsHeaderProps = {
  someNumber: number
}
```

```
const ToolsHeaderColumn = styled('div')`
  padding-top: ${(props: ToolsHeaderProps) => props.someNumber };
`
```

if you're using typescript 2.9+, you can use this:

```
const ToolsHeaderColumn = styled.div<ToolsHeaderProps>`
  padding-top: ${(props) => props.someNumber};
`
```

Comment: I editted the typescript 2.9+ version to account for the fact that specifying the `props` type is unnecessary. That's inferred from the generic parameter